# Will the notification channel importance be overriden by individual notification importance?

Tags: android, notifications, android-support-library

The question is for Android O and above.

For example, I created a notification channel called "default" and set it `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`. Then I've created a notification, added it to the channel and put `IMPORTANCE_HIGH` in its builder. What will be the final priority of the notification?

I didn't find the answer in docs, they say that individual ones are required to support older versions:

> To support devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) or lower, you
>   must also call setPriority() for each notification, using a priority
>   constant from the NotificationCompat class.

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, on Android O and above, NotificationChannel's importance seems to take precedence over individual Notifications' priority levels.

In my own app I manually specify each Notification's priority levels as well to conform to Google's advice that you quoted. I just tried setting a Notification's priority to `PRIORITY_MAX` and send it out via a NotificationChannel with importance `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` and the notification appeared in the status bar without sliding down (like a heads-up display) like the case when you use a NotificationChannel with `IMPORTANCE_HIGH`.

Comment: Yep, I've done the same experiment with the same results, thank you.

Comment: yes even the reverse is true, if I post a `DEFAULT` priority notification inside a notification channel with `IMPORTANCE_HIGH`, individual notification shows up as a high priority heads up notification instead of a regular one.